# JScrollPane not properly stretching horizontal distance in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, frame, jscrollpane, gridbaglayout

I've seen other posts on this subject, but the solutions they found do not apply to me. I am setting a weighted value and using the `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH` constraints as well.

I'm including the whole GUI code I have, just in case my mistake is coming form something other than the GridBagLayout.

I want the scrollable text block on the right to expand the remaining space within the GUI and I have set all the variables that should be attributed to that and yet it still isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

My result:

[image: GridBagLayout result]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestCode extends JFrame {
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea ();
    JComboBox <String> typeComboBox;
    JTextField searchField;
    JTextField fileField;

    public TestCode(){

        setTitle ("GUI Test");
        setSize (600, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible (true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        JButton readButton = new JButton("Read File");
        JButton displayButton = new JButton("Display");
        JButton searchButton = new JButton("Search");


        searchField = new JTextField(10);
        fileField = new JTextField(15);

        typeComboBox = new JComboBox <String> ();
        typeComboBox.addItem("Index");
        typeComboBox.addItem("Type");
        typeComboBox.addItem("Name");




        JPanel container = new JPanel();
            container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 100));
        JPanel filePanel = new JPanel();
            filePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(filePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            filePanel.add(new JLabel("Source file", SwingConstants.LEFT));
                JPanel filePanelTop = new JPanel();
                    filePanelTop.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
                    filePanelTop.add(fileField);
                JPanel filePanelBottom = new JPanel();
                    filePanelBottom.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
                    filePanelBottom.add(readButton);
                    filePanelBottom.add(displayButton);
            filePanel.add(filePanelTop);
            filePanel.add(filePanelBottom);
            filePanel.setMaximumSize(filePanel.getPreferredSize());
            filePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Import File"));
        JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel(); 
            searchPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(searchPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            searchPanel.add(new JLabel("Search target", SwingConstants.LEFT));
                JPanel searchPanelTop = new JPanel();
                    searchPanelTop.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
                    searchPanelTop.add(searchField);
                    searchPanelTop.add(typeComboBox);
            searchPanel.add(searchPanelTop);
            searchPanel.add(searchButton);
            searchPanel.setMaximumSize(searchPanel.getPreferredSize());
            searchPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Search Objects"));

          GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
          c.gridx = 0;
          c.gridy = 0;
          container.add(filePanel, c);
          c.gridx = 0;
          c.gridy = 1;
          container.add(searchPanel, c);
          c.gridx = 1;
          c.gridy = 0;
          c.weightx = 1.0;
          c.weighty = 1.0;
          c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
          c.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
          c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
          c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
          container.add(scrollPane, c);

        add(container, BorderLayout.WEST);

        validate();

    } // end method toString

    public static void main(String[] args){
        TestCode run = new TestCode();
    }
} // end class Treasure
```

Comment: You set visible *before* adding components and never call pack. How can you expect this to work? And don't call `setSize(...)` on anything. Let the components and layout managers size themselves appropriately.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That just screws everything up. The ScrollPanel has no 'size' because it initially has no content, so not setting a size and calling pack() smashes it into nothing. And it also smashes other panels into nothing I guess i just need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: It doesn't have any size because you don't give it any size. You should consider setting thee JTextArea's visible columns and and rows when you create it: `new JTextArea(rows, cols)`, and then let the JScrollPane **along with all other components** size themselves.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you for the tips. I'll keep this in mine moving forward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
//add(container, BorderLayout.WEST);
add(container);
```

The West contrains the components to their preferred width. The default is the CENTER which allows components to expand to fill the space available.

Also, the main structure of you code is wrong. You should be adding all the component to the frame first and then invoke:

```
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Then there is no need for the validate().

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Sometimes the most annoying problems have the most embarrassingly simple solutions.

Comment: Well frame.pack() managed to screw everything up. It 'packs' all the elements and smashes them down into a totally undesirable size and then ignores the window size I declared initially.

Comment: @leigero, that is because you should NOT be using `setPreferredSize()` on any of the components. Each component has its own preferred size. The fact that you used this on your container means all the child components can't fit into the container properly. The GridBagLayout will then shrink the component to its minimum size. Learn to use the layout managers properly. As I told you in your last posting you should NOT be using any of the setXXX methods.

Comment: This exercise is my attempt to better understand GUI layout managers. I just don't get the results I expect more often than not and its very frustrating. I've taken your suggestions into consideration. I'm just trying to work through the seemingly random errors I constantly get. I don't know why anybody would want to create a GUI without a using a tool.